# AttributeError in adding title to ppt slide in python

Tags: python, powerpoint, attributeerror, nonetype, python-pptx

I have been writing a python code for insertion of pictures from a folder into a ppt slide accepted as input from user, and I am getting attribute error for trying to add the image name as title of the slide on which the image is set. The code is :

```
from pptx import Presentation
import os
import sys
from pptx.util import Inches

def ppt_creation_using_snaps(folder_loc, ppt_loc):
    ppt = Presentation(ppt_loc)
    #folder = open(folder_loc)
    folder_list = os.listdir(folder_loc)
    #folder_list.sort()

    for image in folder_list:
        if image.endswith(".png"):
           slide = ppt.slides.add_slide(ppt.slide_layouts[0])
           slide.shapes.title.text = ''.join(element for element in image if not element.isdigit())
           #slide.shapes.title.text = str(image)
           pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(folder_loc + '\\' + image,Inches(0),Inches(0),Inches(9.5))
           #Title = sl.shapes.title
       
    ppt.save(ppt_loc)
```

When I am executing the code, it shows the following error:

[image]

Please help me out for this

Comment: According to https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.shapetree.SlideShapes, ```slide.shapes.title``` is ```None``` if the slide has no title placeholder.  Not entirely sure if this is even applicable to you.  Which version of pptx are you using?

Comment: How do I add a placeholder, @ewong? I am using 0.6.21 version of pptx

Comment: Are you expecting to add a placeholder in code I.e. dynamically? (I can't see the point of that.) But otherwise you would add the placeholder in the master.

Comment: Explore the output of `ppt.slides`, `ppt.slide_layouts` and `ppt.slides.add_slide(ppt.slide_layouts[0])`. We can not test/re-produce the problem as we don't have the PPT file your are using.

Comment: See the slide master of the source pptx file which you are calling by `Presentation(ppt_loc)`, go to layout[0], and see if it indeed has any title placeholder.  Python is not able to access this placeholder.